# Loading swf on IE html

Tags: html, css, flash

```
<div>
  <object id="myMovieName" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
    <param value="/media/camera.swf" name="movie">
    <param value="high" name="quality">
    <param value="#FFFFFF" name="bgcolor">
    <embed align=""
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
           name="myMovieName"
           bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
           quality="high"
           src="/media/camera.swf"
           href="/media/camera.swf">
  </object>
</div>
```

the swf file doesnt load in IE what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Sorry not sometimes its always..I have corrected it..

Comment: Which version of IE? Is the Flash plugin installed?

Comment: Does the Flash load on other browsers than IE?

Comment: Yes flash does load on all the browsers..I am testing this on both IE7 and IE8

Comment: Your "object" tag is missing the codebase attribute.  Might be related to that.  Try to copy the `<object> and <embed> example` from Adobe at http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html and paste in your local values - does the problem still exist?

Answer (score 1):

I really think you should use swfobject. Download it from here:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_2_2.zip&can=2&q=

Then get the expressinstall.swf and the swfobject.js file.

Here is an example code for your stuff:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>SWFObject example</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="language" content="en" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var fo = new Object();
            function initFlash()
            {
                fo.flashvars = {};
                fo.params = {
                    allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain"
                };
                fo.attributes = {};
                swfobject.embedSWF("smedia/camera.swf", "flashcontent", "100%", "100%", "10,1,103", "media/expressInstall.swf", fo.flashvars, fo.params, fo.attributes);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashcontent">Flash will be placed here by swfobject.</div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">initFlash();</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can read more about how it works in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation).

Rob